Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "helloWord", "signature": "helloWord()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.13.4)
I have a problem deploying my smart contract
Hi everyone, I'm learning solidity and hardhat.
I'll explain my problem, to deploy the "Tweet.sol" contract I used ignition by writing the following code:
const { buildModule } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/modules");

module.exports = buildModule ("Twitter", (m) => {
  const twitter = m.contract("Twitter");
  return { twitter };
});


With these lines of code my contract was loaded into my blockchain.
I use the "Twitter.js" file to use the contract and its methods:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    const contractAddress = "0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512";

    const Twitter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Twitter");

    const twitter = await Twitter.attach(contractAddress);

    const value = await twitter.helloWord();
    console.log("VALUE: " + value);

}
    
    main()
      .then(() => process.exit(0))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
      });


I don't know why I can't use this method and any other, solidity code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;
import "./InterfaceTwitter.sol";

contract Twitter is InterfaceTwitter{
    
    mapping (address => string) accounts;
    mapping (address => string[]) tweets;
    string hello = "Hello words!!!!!";

    function createAccount(string memory _nickname )external{
        accounts[msg.sender] = _nickname;
    }

    function createTwitt(string memory _tweet) existAccount(msg.sender) external{
        tweets[msg.sender].push(_tweet);
    }

    modifier existAccount(address _account) {
        require((keccak256(bytes(accounts[_account])) != ""), "ACCOUNT DON'T EXIST  :( ");
        _;
    }

    function helloWord() public view returns(string memory){
        return hello;
    }

    function getNick() view external returns (string memory){
        return accounts[msg.sender];
    }

}

In case, however, I don't go to use the "ignition" deployment but use this code, it works but the deployment of any contract-address doesn't appear in the console:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  try {
    const Twitter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Twitter")
    const contract = await Twitter.deploy();
    
    console.log(`SimpleContract deployed to: ${contract.address}`);
    
    const hello = await contract.helloWord();
    console.log("VALORE DI RITORNO SOLIDITYYYY: " + hello);

    await contract.createAccount("pix");
    const nick = await contract.getNick();
    console.log("THIS IS A MY NIME:     " + nick);



  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();

Someone help me, thanks.
